# Spring Boot- Migrate traditional web application servlet without spring to spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I want to switch my project to Spring based.
I am not finding any guidelines of how to migrate the traditional `web.xml` project's servlet to Spring boot.

Below is my `servlet.java` for your reference.

```
@WebServlet(name = "Servlet")

public class Servlet extends HttpServlet 
{



//final static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("Servlet.class");


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        variables.scrollflag = 1;
        if (request.getParameter("ins") != null) {
            variables.cruiseflag=0;
            variables.flag6 = 0;
            variables.flag9 = 0;
            variables.labelflag = 0;
            variables.displayflag=0;

            String n = request.getParameter("inserttextbox1");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }
            PrintWriter o = response.getWriter();
            o.print(sb.toString());


            String n2 = request.getParameter("inserttextbox2");
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(n2);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb2.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb2.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb2.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }


            String n3 = request.getParameter("inserttextbox3");
            StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder(n3);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb3.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb3.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb3.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try {
                InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../main/resources/database.properties");
                properties.load(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    //            logger.severe("SQL exception. Could not load properties file.");
            }


            Connection conn = null;
            Context ctx = null;
            try {
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/bhdatasource");
                conn=ds.getConnection();
            } catch (Exception c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
      //          logger.severe("SQL exception. Connection URL, User Name or Password is incorrect. Please check the server.xml file.");
            }

            try {
                List<beans> list234 = new ArrayList<>();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("ins_search"));
                pstmt.setString(1, sb.toString());
                pstmt.setString(2, sb2.toString());
                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    beans e1 = new beans();
                    e1.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    e1.setpccma(rs.getString(2));
                    e1.setpccal(rs.getString(3));
                    e1.setcname(rs.getString(4));
                    list234.add(e1);

                    request.setAttribute("searchlist2", list234);
                    String msg = "Record already exists";

                    request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                    conn.close();
                    ctx.close();
                    RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/insertpcc.jsp?page=1");
                    dis.forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }

                List<beans> list = new ArrayList<>();
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("insert"));
                stmt.setString(1, sb.toString());
                stmt.setString(2, sb2.toString());
                stmt.setString(3, sb3.toString());
                stmt.executeUpdate();


                PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("show_insert"));
                stmt1.setString(1, sb2.toString());
                stmt1.setString(2, sb.toString());
                stmt1.setString(3, sb3.toString());
                ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();

                while (rs1.next()) {
                    beans e1 = new beans();
                    e1.setId(rs1.getInt(1));
                    e1.setpccma(rs1.getString(2));
                    e1.setpccal(rs1.getString(3));
                    e1.setcname(rs1.getString(4));
                    list.add(e1);
                }
                request.setAttribute("searchlist2", list);
                String msg = "Row inserted. Flag is set to Y";
                request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                String yflag = "Y";
                PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("updflag"));
                pst.setString(1, yflag);
                pst.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
                conn.close();
                ctx.close();
                RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/insertpcc.jsp?page=1");
                dis.forward(request, response);
                return;


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        //        logger.severe("SQL exception");
            }
            catch (NamingException e) {
          //      logger.severe("Exception in closing Context");
            }
        }

        if (request.getParameter("two") != null || request.getParameter("search") != null) {
            variables.labelflag = 0;
            variables.flag6 = 0;
            variables.flag9 = 0;
            variables.cruiseflag=0;
            variables.displayflag=0;

            String n = request.getParameter("textbox1");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }
            PrintWriter o = response.getWriter();
            o.print(sb.toString());


            String n2 = request.getParameter("textbox2");
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(n2);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb2.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb2.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb2.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try {
                InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../main/resources/database.properties");
                properties.load(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              //  logger.severe("SQL exception. Could not load properties file.");
            }
            Connection conn = null;
            Context ctx=null;
            try {
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/bhdatasource");
                conn=ds.getConnection();
            } catch (Exception c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
            //    logger.severe("SQL exception. Connection URL, User Name or Password is incorrect. Please check the server.xml file.");
            }


            List<beans> list = new ArrayList<>();
            try {

                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("search"));
                PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("search2"));
                stmt.setString(1, sb2.toString());
                stmt2.setString(1, sb2.toString());
                stmt2.setString(2, sb.toString());
                ResultSet rs;
                if (sb.toString().equals("")) {
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                } else {
                    rs = stmt2.executeQuery();
                }

                if (!(rs.isBeforeFirst())) {
                    variables.labelflag = 1;
                    variables.flag6 = 1;
                    String msg = "No records found!";
                    request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                    conn.close();
                    ctx.close();
                    RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/searchpcc.jsp?page=1");
                    dis.forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }

                while (rs.next()) {

                    beans e = new beans();
                    e.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                    e.setpccma(rs.getString(2));
                    e.setpccal(rs.getString(3));
                    e.setcname(rs.getString(4));
                    list.add(e);

                }

                request.setAttribute("searchlist", list);


                conn.close();
                variables.y = 1;
                RequestDispatcher dis1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/searchpcc.jsp?page=1");
                dis1.forward(request, response);
                return;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //logger.severe("SQL exception");
            }
            catch (NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //logger.severe("Exception in closing context");
            }
        }


        if (request.getParameter("upd") != null) {
            variables.cruiseflag=0;
            variables.flag6 = 0;
            variables.ra = 0;
            variables.flag9 = 1;
            variables.displayflag=0;
            variables.labelflag = 0;
            String n = request.getParameter("updatetextbox1");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }
            PrintWriter o = response.getWriter();
            o.print(sb.toString());


            String n2 = request.getParameter("updatetextbox3");
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(n2);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb2.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb2.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb2.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }


            String n3 = request.getParameter("updatetextbox5");
            StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder(n3);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb3.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb3.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb3.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }


            String n21 = request.getParameter("updatetextbox2");
            StringBuilder sb21 = new StringBuilder(n21);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb21.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb21.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb21.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }

            String n22 = request.getParameter("updatetextbox4");
            StringBuilder sb22 = new StringBuilder(n22);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb22.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb22.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb22.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }

            String n23 = request.getParameter("updatetextbox6");
            StringBuilder sb23 = new StringBuilder(n23);
            for (int index = 0; index < sb23.length(); index++) {
                char c = sb23.charAt(index);
                if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                    sb23.setCharAt(index, Character.toUpperCase(c));
                }
            }


            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try {
                InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../main/resources/database.properties");
                properties.load(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              //  logger.severe("SQL exception. Could not load properties file.");
            }


            Connection conn = null;
            Context ctx=null;
            try {
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/bhdatasource");
                conn=ds.getConnection();
            } catch (Exception c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
                //logger.severe("SQL exception. Connection URL, User Name or Password is incorrect. Please check the server.xml file.");
            }

            try {

                List<beans> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
                List<beans> list23 = new ArrayList<>();
                List<beans> list233 = new ArrayList<>();
                PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("updatevalid"));
                PreparedStatement stmt4 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("updatevald2"));
                stmt2.setString(1, sb2.toString());
                stmt2.setString(2, sb.toString());
                stmt4.setString(1, sb2.toString());
                stmt4.setString(2, sb.toString());
                stmt4.setString(3, sb3.toString());
                ResultSet rs9;
                if (sb3.toString().equals("")) {
                    rs9 = stmt2.executeQuery();
                } else {
                    rs9 = stmt4.executeQuery();
                }

                if (!(rs9.isBeforeFirst())) {
                    String msg = "No records found!";
                    request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                    conn.close();
                    ctx.close();
                    RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/updatepcc.jsp?page=1");
                    dis.forward(request, response);
                    return;
                }

                while (rs9.next()) {


                    beans e = new beans();
                    e.setId(rs9.getInt(1));
                    e.setpccma(rs9.getString(2));
                    e.setpccal(rs9.getString(3));
                    e.setcname(rs9.getString(4));
                    list1.add(e);

                }

                request.setAttribute("searchlist31", list1);

                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("updatedup"));
                pstmt.setString(1, sb21.toString());
                pstmt.setString(2, sb22.toString());
                pstmt.setString(3, sb23.toString());
                ResultSet rs11 = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if (rs11.next()) {
                    beans e1 = new beans();
                    e1.setId(rs11.getInt(1));
                    e1.setpccma(rs11.getString(2));
                    e1.setpccal(rs11.getString(3));
                    e1.setcname(rs11.getString(4));
                    list233.add(e1);


                    request.setAttribute("searchlist31", list233);
                    String msg = "No records updated since new values already exists";
                    request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
                    conn.close();
                    ctx.close();
                    RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/updatepcc.jsp?page=1");
                    dis.forward(request, response);
                } else {

                    PreparedStatement stmt, stmt9;
                    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("update1"));
                    stmt.setString(1, sb21.toString());
                    stmt.setString(2, sb22.toString());
                    stmt.setString(3, sb23.toString());
                    stmt.setString(4, sb2.toString());
                    stmt.setString(5, sb.toString());

                    stmt9 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("update2"));
                    stmt9.setString(1, sb21.toString());
                    stmt9.setString(2, sb22.toString());
                    stmt9.setString(3, sb23.toString());
                    stmt9.setString(4, sb2.toString());
                    stmt9.setString(5, sb.toString());
                    stmt9.setString(6, sb3.toString());
                    int no_of_records;
                    if (sb3.toString().equals("")) {
                        no_of_records = stmt.executeUpdate();
                    } else {
                        no_of_records = stmt9.executeUpdate();
                    }

                    PreparedStatement stmt11 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("updatedisp"));
                    stmt11.setString(1, sb22.toString());
                    stmt11.setString(2, sb21.toString());
                    stmt11.setString(3, sb23.toString());
                    ResultSet rs1 = stmt11.executeQuery();
                    while (rs1.next()) {
                        beans e1 = new beans();
                        e1.setId(rs1.getInt(1));
                        e1.setpccma(rs1.getString(2));
                        e1.setpccal(rs1.getString(3));
                        e1.setcname(rs1.getString(4));
                        list23.add(e1);

                    }
                    request.setAttribute("searchlist3", list23);
                    String msg = " row updated. Flag is set to Y";
                    request.setAttribute("msg", no_of_records + msg);
                    String yflag1 = "Y";
                    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("updflag1"));
                    pst.setString(1, yflag1);
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    conn.commit();
                    conn.close();
                    ctx.close();
                    RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/updatepcc.jsp?page=1");
                    dis.forward(request, response);

                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
           //     logger.severe("SQL exception");


            }
            catch (NamingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
         //       logger.severe("Exception in closing context");
            }
        }


        if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
            variables.displayflag=1;
            String[] words0 = request.getParameterValues("cruiselinedropdown");
            String[] words = request.getParameterValues("descriptextbox");
            String[] words2 = request.getParameterValues("starttimetextbox");
            String[] words3 = request.getParameterValues("endtimetextbox");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try {
                InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../main/resources/database.properties");
                properties.load(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              //  logger.severe("SQL exception. Could not load properties file.");
            }


            Connection conn = null;
            Context ctx=null;
            try {
                ctx = new InitialContext();
                DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/bhdatasource");
                conn=ds.getConnection();
            } catch (Exception c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
         //      logger.severe("SQL exception. Connection URL, User Name or Password is incorrect. Please check the server.xml file.");
            }
            int cruisemaxid=0;
            try {
                PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("maxid"));
                ResultSet rsmaxid2 = pstmt2.executeQuery();
                if(rsmaxid2.next()){
                    cruisemaxid=rsmaxid2.getInt("idmax");
                }


                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("cruiseinsert"));
                for(int i=0;i<words2.length;i++)
                {
                pstmt.setInt(1,cruisemaxid+i+1);
                pstmt.setString(2,words0[i]);
                pstmt.setString(3,words2[i]);
                pstmt.setString(4,words3[i]);
                pstmt.setString(5,words[i]);
                pstmt.addBatch();
            }
                int[] result=pstmt.executeBatch();
                String cruiserowsinserted = "No. of rows inserted : "+result.length;
                request.setAttribute("cruiserowsinserted", cruiserowsinserted);
                conn.commit();
                conn.close();
                ctx.close();
                doGet(request,response);



            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            //    logger.severe("SQL exception");

            }
            catch (NamingException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
             //   logger.severe("Exception in closing context");
            }
        }









    }








    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(variables.displayflag==1)variables.displayflag=1;
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../main/resources/database.properties");
            properties.load(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        Context ctx=null;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/bhdatasource");
            conn=ds.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
         //   logger.severe("SQL exception. Connection URL, User Name or Password is incorrect. Please check the server.xml file.");
        }

        List<beans> cruiselinelist3 = new ArrayList<>();

        List<beans> cruiselinelist = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps3=conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("crzcode"));
            ResultSet rscruise3 = ps3.executeQuery();

            while (rscruise3.next()) {
                beans ecruise3 = new beans();
                ecruise3.setCruisecode(rscruise3.getString("CRZCODE"));
                cruiselinelist3.add(ecruise3);
            }
            request.setAttribute("cruiselist3",cruiselinelist3);

            PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement(properties.getProperty("cruiselines"));
            ResultSet rscruise = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rscruise.next()) {
                beans ecruise = new beans();
                ecruise.setCruiseline(rscruise.getString(1));
                cruiselinelist.add(ecruise);
            }
            request.setAttribute("cruiselist",cruiselinelist);
            conn.close();
            ctx.close();
            RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/cruisedowntime.jsp?page=1");
            dis.forward(request, response);

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
         //   logger.severe("SQL exception");


        }
        catch (NamingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         //   logger.severe("Exception in closing context");
        }


        }
}}
```

Comment: Check this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-convert-an-existing-application-to-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks! @SauliusNext But I think it creates a war file right? Actually I wanted a jar file